# C++ virtual inheritance initializer list

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

in the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    A(int x):x(x){}
};

class B: public virtual A
{
public:
    B(int x):A(x){}
};
class C: public virtual A
{
public:
    C(int x):A(x){}
};
class D: public B, public C
{
public:
    D(int x):B(x++), C(x++), A(x++){}
};
```

two questions:

1. Why do I need to add `A(...)` in D's initializer list?
2. `D(int x):B(x++), C(x++), A(x++){}` and `D(int x):A(x++), B(x++), C(x++){}` both give the same result with `cout<<D(10).x`, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why do I need to add A(...) in D's initializer list?

That's because virtual base subobjects must be initialized before all other subobjects. Since `A` does not have a default constructor, you need to initialize the virtual `A` subobject in `D` explicitly and specify which argument you want it to be constructed with.

When the constructors of the `B` and `C` base subobjects are executed, they won't have a base `A` subobject to initialize (that has been done before already). Therefore, the arguments they pass to `A`'s constructor are irrelevant.

> `D(int x):B(x++), C(x++), A(x++){}` and `D(int x):A(x++), B(x++), C(x++){}` both give the same result with `cout<<D(10).x`, why?

As explained above, that's because virtual base subobjects are initialized first anyway.

In general, the order of initialization of a class's subobjects never depends on the order in which they appear in your constructor's initialization list. Per paragraph 12.6.2/10 of the C++11 Standard:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> — **First**, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), **virtual base classes are initialized in
>   the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes**,
>   where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized *in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list*
>   (regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
>
> — Then, non-static data members are initialized *in the order they were declared in the class definition*
>   (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
>
> — Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual base classes are only initialised by the most-derived class. That is, if create an instance of `D` in your example, `A` will only be initialised by its occurence in the mem-initialiser list of `D`. Its occurence in the mem-initialiser lists of `B` and `C` is simply ignored.

That is also why you have to initialise `A` in `D`: `A` doesn't have a default ctor, so `D` must know how to initialise it.